# Modify the objects of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, mern

I want to modify the objects of an array of objects (jsonStudent).

```
   [
    { Student: 'Riya', Gender: 'Female', Pet: 'Timmy' },
    { Student: 'Happy', Gender: 'Male', Pet: 'Harry' },
    { Student: 'Tiya', Gender: 'Female', Pet: 'Timmy' },
   ]
```

And my expected output is(input):

```
  [ 
    {
     name: 'Riya',
     gender: 'Female',
     pet: 'Timmy',
     isActive: true,
     createdAt: 2022-06-28T17:55:53.907Z,
     updatedAt: 2022-06-28T17:55:53.907Z
   },
   {
     name: 'Happy',
     gender: 'Male',
     pet: 'Harry',
     isActive: true,
     createdAt: 2022-06-28T17:55:53.913Z,
     updatedAt: 2022-06-28T17:55:53.913Z
  },
  {
     name: 'Tiya',
     gender: 'Female',
     pet: 'Timmy',
     isActive: true,
     createdAt: 2022-06-28T17:55:53.919Z,
     updatedAt: 2022-06-28T17:55:53.919Z
    }
   ]
```

For that I used this lines of code, but instead of all objects I am getting only the 1st object in output,Can anyone please help me to get all the objects as my expected output.

```
        console.log(jsonStudent);
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonStudent.length; i++) {
            const nameVal = jsonStudent[i].Student;
            const genderVal = jsonStudent[i].Gender;
            const petVal = jsonStudent[i].Pet;
            const now = new Date();
            const input = {
                name: nameVal,
                gender: genderVal,
                pet: petVal,
            };
            input.isActive = true;
            input.createdAt = now;
            input.updatedAt = now;
            console.log(input);
```

Comment: What are you referring to as "output"?

Comment: console.log(input);

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(jsonStudent);
const output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < jsonStudent.length; i++) {
  output.push({
    name: jsonStudent[i].Student,
    gender: jsonStudent[i].Gender,
    pet: jsonStudent[i].Pet,
    isActive: true,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    updatedAt: new Date()
  });
}
console.log(output);
```

Does what you're after. I've taken the liberty of changing a fair amount there, but it should be fairly self explanatory.

I think your issue was that you weren't storing the results anywhere...

Line 2 shows the creation of the `output` array (before the for loop starts), and then each student's data object is pushed on to the array on line 4.

Finally, once the loop is finished and closed, the `output` array is logged to the console.

Comment: Cool, please upvote and mark as the solution if that's the case. :)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is perfect, but if you want a more functional approach, you can use map to iterate your array. If you do not want to modify your original array, you can use object.assign as in the example.

```
let newStudents = jsonStudents.map(student => {
    let newStudent = Object.assign({}, student);
    newStudent.isActive = true;
    newStudent.createdAt = new Date();
    newStudent.updatedAt = new Date();
    return newStudent;
});
console.log(newStudents);
```

If you do not care about modifying your original array, you can do something like this:

```
    let newStudents = jsonStudents.map(student => {
        student.isActive = true;
        student.createdAt = new Date();
        student.updatedAt = new Date();
        return student;
    });
```